# How tell plugman that I want to update a file that may not be present?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I wrote an android phonegap 3 plugin that starts an activity (the activity is part of plugin) and uses a native android UI.
Now I want to follow the [plugin specification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html) to be able to install the plugin using the CLI.

My plugin has resources in the xml files /res/values/attrs.xml, /res/values/colors.xml and /res/values/ids.xml

My issue is that those files are not created by the `platform add android` command, so I can't use `<config-file>` to patch them.

I don't want to use `<source-file>` because I would like to avoid conflicts if I have to install other plugins also using those files.

Is there a proper way to update a file if it exists or create it if it doesn't?