# Merge files while adding Cordova Plugins

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins

I develop android plugins for Cordova project and i've stucked with a problem: merging files. In particular resource files. Most plugins have the same resource files like strings.xml, and i want to merge them. I searched Google for several days and couldn't find the answer.

What should I write in plugin.xml of my plugin? Source-file tag just add file. Config-file tag allow me to add some lines to the file, but it's uncomfortably, if I have very much lines. Is there any command to merge files?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem as you and found no way to merge resources using plugman (maybe this has changed in the last couple of years).

What I did is that I made a plugin containing all the common files with a basic content like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
</resources>
```

Then in each plugin where I need to set resources, I use plugman syntax in plugin.xml :

```
<config-file target="res/values/ids.xml" parent="/resources">
    <item type="id" name="id1"/>
    <item type="id" name="id2"/>
    <item type="id" name="id3"/>
</config-file>
<config-file target="res/values/strings.xml" parent="/resources">
    <string name="message1">Hello</string>
    <string name="message2">world!</string>
</config-file>
```

And finally in your plugin you can set a demendency on the "basic resources" plugin.

The limit of this system is if you want to publish your plugins and people use it at the same time as other plugins overwriting the same resources files as you do...

I had posted [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002934/how-tell-plugman-that-i-want-to-update-a-file-that-may-not-be-present) back in the time and had no luck getting an aswer.
I guess we could ask this directly to the plugman people on their jira.

Comment: I hope, they will add merge feature in the future

Comment: This does seem like a good way to do small oneoffs for values, but does not really cover more complex layouts and styles.

Answer (score 3):

Little bit late here;

You can just create `your_plugin_strings.xml` and use `target-dir` to add this to your values folder. The values can then be used as if they were in `strings.xml` like "`@string/your_plugin_hello_message`"

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well. Another possibility, though definitely a work-around for plugins you control (have source downloaded, not using PhoneGap Builder), is to add your resource values to never-used version modifiers of the values folder. See [Android Resources Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Android allows for modifiers based on Android versions, and any resource folder can use these modifers. By "cheating" and putting your strings into `res/values-v1`, for example, allows a separate folder for your strings.xml to exist in, without overwriting an different plugin's values. Any Android device using android v1 or higher, (Honeycomb was v13, Kitkat is v19, Lollipop 5.0 is 21, 5.1 is 22, etc)

You would have to do this with a different version number for each plugin, but there are plenty of versions before hitting Gingerbread (v9), so unless you're super plugin heavy, this workaround could solve the problem in the short term.

If Android uses it's modifiers the way I think it does, your plugins' values will gain automatic preference since the value is "more specific" than the default values folder, with the closest matching vN folder getting the most preference.

If I'm mistaken, however, yours would NOT get preference, so it would be on you to debug/discover naming conflicts and adjust yours accordingly.